# ERROR: Could not find com.android.location.build:gradle:3.5.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I would like to know how I can solve this error:

> ERROR: Could not find com.android.location.build:gradle:3.5.0

Android studio gave me four links to search in, but all links said that an error no more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `com.android.location.build:gradle:3.5.0` **doesn't** exist.

In the top-level `build.gradle` file change to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'`

Comment: Thank you, i deleted the com.android.location.build:gradle:3.5.0 and let classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'